# Pre select form input based on params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a button on an index page that links to a new_assignment_path

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to user.name, user %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Assign to Class', new_assignment_path, :class => 'btn btn-mini' %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

And I want it so that when you click on it, it takes you to the new_assignment_path, and takes the dropdown select on that pages form.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@assignment) do |f| %>
 <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
<%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all.collect, as: :select %>
 </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And have the drop down automatically set to the user.id of whatever user the button was inside of.

```
<%= link_to 'Assign to Project', new_assignment_path(@assignment, :user_id => user.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

and

```
<%= link_to 'Assign to Project', new_assignment_path(:user_id => user.id), :class => 'btn btn-mini' %>
```

And neither of them worked.
What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Please post your `AssignmentController#new` action as well, as that is where setting up the new assigment is supposed to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your second option try setting the instance variable in the AssignmentsController.

`@user_id = params[:user_id]`

Then you need to specify the default in the form

`<%= f.input :user_id, collection: User.all.collect, selected: @user_id %>`

You don't need `as: :select` with Simple Form.